# Python3 diamond pattern definition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I write down my code as follow but, my teacher said I have to return the pattern. I used print() and I have no idea for this. Please help me.

```
def diamond(num):

    a = 1
    b = int((num - 1) / 2)
    c = num - 2
    d = 1
    for i in range(0, int((num - 1) / 2)):
        print( " " * b + a * "*")
        a += 2
        b -= 1
    if num % 2 == 1:
        print("*" * num)
        for i in range(0, int((num - 1) / 2)):
            print( " " * d + c * "*")
            c -= 2
            d += 1
    else:
        print("*" * (num - 1))
        print("*" * (num - 1))
        c = num - 3
        for i in range(0, int((num - 1) / 2)):
            print( " " * d + c * "*")
            c -= 2
            d += 1
```

Comment: use  `yield` instead of `print` and iterate

Comment: What pattern are you trying to produce?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I'm not sure that's a good first technique to learn when you are struggling with print vs return..

Comment: Thanks but I must use "return"...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm *deliberately* not going to write the code for you, but instead giving you pointers as to how you can solve the problem on your own.

Currently, your function uses multiple `print()` function calls to write lines to the console. Your teacher wants you to return those lines, as a single value, to the caller of the function.

There are two problems you must overcome:

1. you must collect all those lines you are now printing into a single string to return.
2. you must add the newlines that `print()` would add, manually.

The easiest way to do this is to use a list, to which you append each string you are printing.

- Put a new variable at the top of your function, assign an empty list. A name like `lines` would probably be a good idea.
- Append each line you are now printing, to that list. The list type has a method to append a value to it, you can trivially replace all the `print()` calls with that method.
- At the end of the function, use a single string method to *concatenate* all the values in the list into one long string. You specify a string to put between the values, if you use the `'\n'` string then Python will use a newline character (`\...` is an escape sequence, `\n` produces a *newline* character)
- return the resulting single string.

You can find the methods needed for this in the [*Built-in Types* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html).

You could also use a string variable at the top, then concatenating each string you now print, to that variable, adding a newline each time. But experienced programmers use a list instead, because that's *cheaper* for a computer program to process. Concatenating a string to another string requires the computer to create a whole new copy for the result, so it has to read all the characters of the old string, all the characters of the concatenated string, and then create a copy of all those characters to put into a new string. You then do the same for the next string you concatenate, but now the result is longer still. You end up making a lot of copies of those initial characters.

Appending a value to a list doesn't have to make a copy, on the other hand, and you then only have to create a copy of all the characters in all the strings in the list *once* to create the output. In terms of [*algorithmic complexity*](https://devopedia.org/algorithmic-complexity), repeatedly concatenating a string takes O(n**2) time (for *n* strings, concatenating takes *quadradic* time, add one more string and the time doubles), while appending those same strings to a list only takes O(n) time (for *n* strings, adding one more takes *linear* time, add one more string and the time grows proportionally).

For a half a dozen strings, the difference is not going to be noticeable, but when your program has to process thousands of lines, things can get out of hand quickly. Concatenating a thousand strings in a loop can take a thousand times more time than adding those same strings to a list first, then joining them together afterwards. It quickly becomes obvious why programmers have to care about these little details.

Comment: spoilsport - now I would feel bad to post my solution :/ +1 to yours.

Comment: another fantastic answer by Martijn-  perhaps another hint would be:  return ''.join(list)

Comment: @TimothyLombard: *At the end of the function, use a single string method to concatenate all the values in the list into one long string.*

Comment: @TimothyLombard: and you want to use a newline character, not an empty string.

Comment: or use something along the lines of `print(*diamonds(width), sep = '\n')` which decomposes the list into single parameters to print and prints them with a seperator that makes linebreaks between them ....

Comment: @PatrickArtner: that depends on the exact requirements. If the specification states that a single string must be returned, then no. If a list of strings *without newlines* is acceptable, then yes.